# How to mount local folder in docker using jupyter with tensorflow image

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have a trouble with mounting local folder with jupyter in tensorflow.

I use Ubuntu 20.04. And I installed all necessaries for tensorflow container.
But when I try to mount local folder with it, then I open default folder instead of local one.

This is my bash command.

`docker run --gpus all -it --rm v$(pwd)/home/peter/Documents/python:/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`

Is there any mistakes?
Thank you in advance.

---

edit

This is my bash. Still it shows default directory.

```
(base) peter@peterpc:~/Documents$ docker run -d --rm --gpus all -p 8888:8888 -v $PWD/python:/tf/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
dbf0debcaf3ebcd409ed3d2c73f61e12a59bef9d4cf31090656c6a9462a4acfb
(base) peter@peterpc:~/Documents$ docker log
docker: 'log' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
(base) peter@peterpc:~/Documents$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
dbf0debcaf3e        tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter   "bash -c 'source /et…"   26 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds       0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp   clever_solomon
(base) peter@peterpc:~/Documents$ docker logs dbf0debcaf3e
[I 12:12:15.498 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 12:12:15.698 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tf
[I 12:12:15.698 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
[I 12:12:15.698 NotebookApp] http://dbf0debcaf3e:8888/?token=066b76ca68eb22fe1cdd1e02f65c7a58f4cd713be19e3516
[I 12:12:15.698 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=066b76ca68eb22fe1cdd1e02f65c7a58f4cd713be19e3516
[I 12:12:15.698 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:12:15.701 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://dbf0debcaf3e:8888/?token=066b76ca68eb22fe1cdd1e02f65c7a58f4cd713be19e3516
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=066b76ca68eb22fe1cdd1e02f65c7a58f4cd713be19e3516
```

---

edit again

I got it inside notebooks folder of root. I didn't know that. Thank you for  answers.

Comment: You are starting the container in interactive terminal `-it` mode, so you should be passing any start command like your tensorflow command or bash or sh. The argument for volume mapping is `-v <host dir/file>:<container dir/file>`. Please correct your `docker run` command to something like this: `docker run -d --rm --gpus all -p 8888:8888 -v $PWD/python:/tf/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`, where $PWD is your current directory (it stands for _Print Working Directory_ in Linux)

Comment: I tried with that command, but still it shows default directory.

Comment: Thank you that I now know $PWD is current directory.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to put - before v. Let me know if it work

-v $PWD/python:/tf/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

Comment: I tried it with putting '-' before v, but still it shows default directory. I don't know why though.

Comment: Did you check if its mounting the directory and not creating and mounting docker volume?

Comment: Yes. I checked docker mounting it. But, when I hard code, it said ```"$/home/peter/Documents/python" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.``` And I can't run docker.

Comment: Dont use $ here. If you are running command from /home/peter/Documents/python use ./ only

Comment: `docker run -d --rm -p 8888:8888 -v ./ tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter` results in bash showing **docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: open /proc/self/attr/exec: no such file or directory\"": unknown.**

Comment: `docker run -d --rm -p 8888:8888 -v /home/peter/Documents/python tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter` results showing default folder.

Comment: docker run -d --rm -p 8888:8888 -v /home/peter/Documents/python:/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter  :p this will be the command

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

`sudo docker run --gpus all --rm -it -p 8888:8888 -v /path/to/your/folder:/tf tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`